# Ways to secure my own site for personal use?

Tags: tls, certificates, http, openssl

I created an azure VM and installed Gitlab's omnibus package in it. I'm using it as my personal git repo and a couple of my friends use it too. The problem is that is it not secure, it's using http. You can easily see the password being used in login if you monitor the http traffic using Wireshark or fiddler. I don't want to spend money to buy a certificate from a CA. Is there any other way I can secure that site?

Comment: I actually don't know that. I'll read about it thanks.

Comment: @LanceContreras: apart from being a duplicate to other questions on how to be secure without SSL:  1. SSL certificates can be free as drewbenn already pointed out, 2. SSL does not magically make a site secure. It only protects against the specific attack of sniffing and man in the middle. But it does not help against XSS, CSRF, SQL injection and many other possible and common attacks.